# Emulator error with AOSP compilation

Tags: android, compilation, android-virtual-device, android-source

I have synced AOSP project master branch and build successfully. But when i run emulator command it says

```
emulator: ERROR: There`s another emulator instance running with the current AVD '<build>'. Exiting ...
```

for the first time emulator was started with a message (can`t remember complete message) that
avd is outdated please update using android studio.
Then I installed android studio and after that its giving above message. What could be a possible solution for this. 
I am using ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem as yours.
Please open your Android Studio and the AVD, try to change the name of the avd. 
In this way, I find my avd in the aosp name changes, too.

```
 emulator -list-avds
```

I choose to compile the project again.